# How to call out a data using an id from the displayed table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to call out a the other data from the database and display it through modal but i cant call out the ID from my html table.

Here's my html table and php for posting some of the data's :

```
<?php
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password
        mysql_select_db('ts_php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM job_posted"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        echo "<table class='table'>
                <thead>
                          <th>JOB</th>
                          <th>STATUS</th>
                          <th>APPLICATIONS</th>
                          <th>EDIT</th>
                          <th>DELETE</th>
                </thead>
            "; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr>
            <th>" . $row['job_title'] . "</th>
                <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['applications'] . "</td>
                <td><a class='openModal' data-id='".$row['post_ID']."'>edit</a></td>
                <td><a href='#'>delete</a></td>                  
            </tr>";
    }

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

     ?>
```

And here is my php inside the modal body

```
<?php 
    (LINE 121:) $queryEdit = "SELECT * FROM job_posted WHERE post_ID = '$row['post_ID']' ";
    $resultEdit = mysql_query($queryEdit, $connection);
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultEdit)){        
?>
<span>Name:</span> <?php echo $row1['job_title']; ?><br>
<span>loc:</span> <?php echo $row1['location']; ?><br>
<span>job type:</span> <?php echo $row1['job_type']; ?><br>
<span>description:</span> <?php echo $row1['job_desc']; ?><br>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Here is the Execution error 
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\talent_space_php\employer\jobs_posted.php on line 121

PS. I just knew recently that the mysql_* will be depreciated, so im planning to finish this first and then convert into MYSQLI or PDO.

Comment: *I just knew recently that the mysql_* will be depreciated* It is deprecated and removed in actual php versions

Comment: What is the Problem with your code?

Comment: But i still can use it... nvm that part. the problem was in the second PHP code, it dont display any result. I think it cant fetch the id from the 1st php code

Comment: So is there any other way to fetch the row['ID'] and use it in WHERE id = 'row['ID']'?

Comment: print out the Statement and see if it is as expected. Also check for SQL Errors after execution the statement

Comment: Tried, didnt work...

Comment: you have written line 121 but we don't know which line it is in your code.

Comment: I forgot to include the error state, i edited it and included it now

Comment: omg sorry.. wait im really new into this

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\talent_space_php\employer\jobs_posted.php on line 121 @Jens

Comment: the variable $row['post_ID'] doesn't exist or is not a string. It means that it doesn't know where to get the variable from.

Comment: Yes thats my problem, i cant get the row id from the table. thats why theres no display into my modal, i think

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: it didnt... but still thanks for that

Comment: If you still can't figure it out, you can give me your source code and I'll try to figure it out for you. You learn programming by solving things like these. Also watch some pdo php tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar recently.
The way i worked around it was this:
While generating my rows i added `data` properties to my modal toggler (in my case a button). Just like you added `data-id`. However i did this for every value that i need.
I simply used a jquery function to add my data into input fields inside of my modal.

Button table row generation:

```
<td><a href="#" class="editId" data-hidden="' . $product['id'] . '" data-name="' . $product['name'] .'" 
    data-short="' . $product['kuerzel'] . '"data-anr="' . $product['anumber'] . '" 
    data-comment="' . $product['comment'] . '" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#editProductModal"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></td>
```

My Modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <input type="hidden" name="action2" value="edit">
   <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col-4">
          <div class="form-group">
             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="hidden" id="modal_hidden" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="select_p" class="col-form label">Produkt:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="select" id="select_p" value="" required disabled>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="new_products_add_name" class="col-form label">New Name:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="new_name" id="new_products_add_name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="new_products_add_short" class="col-form label">New Short:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="new_short" id="new_products_add_short">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="new_products_add_number" class="col-form label">New ProductNr:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="new_number" pattern="{3,11}" id="new_products_add_number">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="new_products_add_comment" class="col-form label">New Comment:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="new_comment" id="new_products_add_comment">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Function:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click",".editId",function() {
            var hidden_value = $(this).data('hidden');
            var name_value = $(this).data('name');
            var short_value = $(this).data('short');
            var anr_value = $(this).data('anr');
            var comment_value = $(this).data('comment');
            $('#modal_hidden').val(hidden_value);
            $('#select_p').val(name_value);
            $('#new_products_add_name').val(name_value);
            $('#new_products_add_short').val(short_value);
            $('#new_products_add_number').val(anr_value);
            $('#new_products_add_comment').val(comment_value);
        });
</script>
```

I hope this helps. This might not be the cleanest way of doing this, but it worked for me (and my table contains a fairly large number of rows).

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to not echo out html values.

Second, I would use pdo there are enough examples on the internet. A few tutorials should help you out.

As of your problem:

Change this:

```
$queryEdit = "SELECT * FROM job_posted WHERE post_ID = '$row['post_ID']' ";
```

Into one of these:

```
$queryEdit = "SELECT * FROM job_posted WHERE post_ID = " + $row['post_ID'];
$queryEdit = "SELECT * FROM job_posted WHERE post_ID = {$row['post_ID']} ";
```